# 2 instances of sc.rtm_read() not working simultaneously using threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, slack-api, slack

I am making a slackbot using python-slackclient. For every conversation - I am creating a separate thread and listening to RTM on it.

But sc.rtm_read() are not running simultaneously together. Its only running in main and not in threaded function.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
from slackclient import SlackClient
import time
token = "xoxb-47823XXXX1-11mYmUuXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

def other(sc2):
    print "other"
    while True:
        new_evts = sc2.rtm_read()
        for evt in new_evts:
            print "second"
            print evt
            if "type" in evt:
                if evt["type"] == "message" and "text" in evt:    
                    message=evt["text"]
                    print message
            time.sleep(1)


def main():
    sc = SlackClient(token)
    if sc.rtm_connect():
        t1=Thread(target=other,args=(sc,))
        t1.start()
        time.sleep(10)
        while True:
            new_evts = sc.rtm_read()
            for evt in new_evts:
                print evt
                if "type" in evt:
                    if evt["type"] == "message" and "text" in evt:    
                        message=evt["text"]
                        print message
                time.sleep(1)
main()
```

Now Only the one in other works. For main() i am getting error - "***error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable***
". how to get both of rtm_read() work?

Comment: You could either open two sockets (`rtm_connect` twice and use one socket per thread), or you could use one socket and route messages to threads using a queue or something similar.